# How Can I write the Css for this Style

Tags: css

Hi I try to edit the css of wordpress themes but I get stuck when I saw this DIV Style.

```
     <li id="text-3" class="widget sbg_widget Phubadee widget_text">
        <h2 class="widgettitle  sbg_title">Title Header</h2>
```

How Can I make the CSS When I want the : Title Header : font-size: 1.6em;

Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi you can define #text-3 .widgettitle.sbg_title{font-size:1.6em;}

Answer (score 2):

```
h2.widgettitle.sbg_title { font-size:1.6em }
```

Explanation:

`.` is a class selector in css, your `h2` has class `widgettitle` and `sbg_title`, so we would like to select those two by using `.`.

Note that there can't be any space between `widgettitle` and the next `.`, having space means entirely different thing, which is selecting *any* descendant of `widgettitle` that has class `sbg_title`

Answer (score 2):

There is more way to do that.If you want you can add this to you css

```
h2.widgettitle {font-size:1.6em;}
```

or if you want to be more specific

```
h2.widgettitle .sbg_tittle
```

Comment: Code is described by prepending each line with 4 spaces. Please refer to the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 2):

There are alot of way you can do it. Any of these will work, and there are more ways to do it!

```
li.widget h2 { font-size:1.6em }

li.sbg_widget h2 { font-size:1.6em }

h2 { font-size:1.6em }

h2.widgettitle { font-size:1.6em }

h2.sbg_title { font-size:1.6em }

.widgettitle { font-size:1.6em } 

.sbg_title { font-size:1.6em }

li h2 { font-size:1.6em }

li>h2 { font-size:1.6em }

li#text-3 h2 { font-size:1.6em }

li#text-3 h2.widgettitle { font-size:1.6em }

li#text-3 h2.sbg_title { font-size:1.6em }
```

If you want to learn about CSS selectors, [Sitepoint](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/selectorref) has a good breakdown of what they are and how they work

Answer (score 0):

You can select that item in many ways, try for example

```
li#text-3 h2.sbg_title {
     font-size: 1.6em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:
        .widgettitle.sbg_title {font-size:1.6em;}

Option 2:
        .sbg_title {font-size:1.6em;}

Option 3:
        .widgettitle {font-size:1.6em;}